# Rails engine and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, content-management-system, rails-engines

I have a Rails Engine, where I want to use Devise. I installed devise like normal following [this guide](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Use-devise-inside-a-mountable-engine).

I added this in my engine devise.rb:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.router_name = :cms_user
end
```

I added this in my routes file:

```
Cms::User::Engine.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, {
    class_name: 'Cms::User',
    module: :devise
  }
end
```

I added this in my routes:

```
devise_for :users, {
  class_name: 'Cms::User',
  module: :devise
}
```

However I keep getting this error:

```
undefined method 'cms_user'
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I have also tried to add devise to a brand new plugin, and added the this in my engine routes file:   devise_for :users, {
      class_name: 'Blorgh::User',
      module: :devise
    }   and this in my devise file config.router_name = :blorgh_instant_user

Comment: Any luck trying to solve this?  I may have run into the same issue, though I'm not sure:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879350/why-doesnt-authenticate-admin-give-an-undefined-method-error-for-a-rails-engine

Comment: Hi! - Yes I solved it with, please look at the latest anwser. Also I found that when mounting the engine, it's important to specify a path, otherwise the Devise routes wont work (for example: mount Cms::Engine => "/cms")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the how to:

1. Rails plugin new cms --mountable -d postgresql

2: Install devise like normal

3: Add this in the main application routes file:

```
  devise_for :users, {
     class_name: 'Cms::User',
     module: :devise
   }
```

This line here, mentioned in the devise wiki, caused the problems for me:

```
config.router_name = :Cms_user
```

Wiki:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-devise-inside-a-mountable-engine

Comment: If we add this engine into our master app, can the master app user filters, such as authenticate_user! ?