# Why does my Rails 3.2.3 Application fail because my Engine plugin has devise installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a Rails application called `bdm_content_server`

I have a Rails Engine plugin called `bdmcs`.

The engine is installed as a local file gem in my application.

```
gem "bdmcs", :path => "../bdmcs"
```

The Engine was running fine, and I was able to access it's controllers and views through application when running WEBrick.

I installed devise inside of the engine to control who had access to the engine's views.  The setup went fine (with a little modification ala [Rails engine and devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838863/rails-engine-and-devise)), and I'm able to execute the database migrations within the engine, but now when I attempt to migrate the Application that it's installed in I'm getting an error:

```
undefined method `secret_key=' for Devise:Module
/var/apps/bdm_content/bdmcs/config/initializers/devise.rb:7:in `block in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.8/lib/devise.rb:267:in `setup'
/var/apps/bdm_content/bdmcs/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

The application doesn't appear to be acknowledging the engine's devise setup and configuration.

I have the devise gem installed in the Gemfile for the application, and if I remove it I get a different error:

```
cannot load such file -- devise
/var/apps/bdm_content/bdmcs/lib/bdmcs.rb:1:in `require'
/var/apps/bdm_content/bdmcs/lib/bdmcs.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Anyone have any thoughts?

I've searched around for similar questions but have only found ones related to either Devise in an Application or Devise in an Engine, but not one where both are involved.

Thanks in Advance
 - Testero

Here's my /bdmcs/config/initializers/devise.rb file (as installed in my engine by Devise):

```
Devise.setup do |config|
    config.secret_key = 'some_random_key'
    config.mailer_sender = 'please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com'
    require 'devise/orm/active_record'
    config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]
    config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]
    config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
    config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10
    config.reconfirmable = true
    config.password_length = 8..128
    config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
    config.sign_out_via = :delete
    config.router_name = :bdmcs_user
end
```

And my /bdmcs/lib/bdcms.rb file:

```
require 'devise'
require "bdmcs/engine"

module Bdmcs
end
```

EDITED - Clarity and further detail

Answer (score 0):

In your `config/initializers/devise.rb` file add this line:

```
config.secret_key = 'Your secret Key'
```

You can use `rake secret` to generate your secret key.

Make sure your using the latest version of Devise in your Gemfile.

Also make sure you restart your server. 99% of my problems went away after doing this.

Comment: This line is already set in the devise.rb inside of my Engine plugin, but that's where it's stumbling.  It's as if the config variable is not being set because devise is not being recognized outside of the engine. 

Or are you saying add it to my application as well? I do not have a devise.rb initializer there.

Comment: Ok and you have require 'devise' in your engine.rb

Comment: Yes, I've updated the question with the content of that file.

Comment: Ok I don't really understand what the issue is. I take you have looked at this: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-devise-inside-a-mountable-engine

Comment: The issue is that when I attempt to do a db:migrate on the application, it fails because it isn't properly acknowledging the Devise install that exists within the engine (errors posted in the question).   So I effectively can't do anything with my application.  Can't run the server, can't migrate the database, nothing.

I used the link you provided when I initially setup Devise inside the engine, but thanks for the link.

Comment: Ok just trying to help. I take it dropping the whole database doesn't help or reinstalling devise. Sorry I must admit when I'm out my depth.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that it was a Devise versioning issue.

For some reason, devise inside the engine was being installed at version 3.2.2 and the devise installed in the app was 2.2.8

Not sure how that happened, because I didn't specify any particular version, and both were generated in the same rails environment.

After I upgraded, I got a version conflict between Railties and Devise, so I ultimately had to upgrade Rails to 4.0.0 (and all the other things that come with that), and then it worked.

I am still having a bundler version problem, but I have resolved that using `bundle exec ...` to execute my rake and rails tasks.